# Does spray mount adhesive damage the paint on walls after the object attached to it is removed?

Tags: walls, paint, mounting

I would like to place posters on walls using a *spray mount adhesive*, such as [link to 3M product on amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/SprayMount-YP208060548-3M-Adhesive-400ml/dp/B000J6D4SA). It is said that the use of the adhesive will create a delicate transparent gel on the object that is to be placed on a wall, but I am unsure if it will create damage or alter the paint/plaster on the wall itself. Will the gel be able to be removed from the wall as well without damaging the wall?

Comment: The adhesive should not damage paint but the solvents required to completely remove dried residue very likely will. You will likely find this adhesive will not hold in the long run, especially poster corners. Any adhesive strong enough to hold securely for extended periods will be very difficult to remove without damage. This is based on personal experience, I have no authoritative references, thus leaving a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: 3M has really good tech service, both email and phone. Ask their advice.

Answer (score 1):

I've had acoustic foam on my walls for a for a year, it's stuck with caned spray on adhesive and it doesn't seem to be damaging my walls, but I can imagine that with stronger spray-on It could be really difficult to remove it without damaging the walls